# How to leave mark region highlighted when switching windows

Tags: window, region, transient-mark-mode

I usually have my Emacs frame split into windows. I'll select something in one window and then switch to another buffer. When I do this Emacs removes the active-region highlghting in the original window. I'd like to keep it highlighted so I know what I was focused on while working in the other window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`highlight-nonselected-windows` is a variable defined in `xdisp.c`.  Its default value is `nil`.  A `non-nil` value means highlight region even in nonselected windows.  You can customize this variable, e.g.:

```
(setq highlight-nonselected-windows t)
```